# Unable to create a Java NetBeans project inside Dropbox folder

Tags: java, netbeans, dropbox

Since last year I've been using NetBeans as my main IDE for college reasons, we must code our exams using that IDE so (unfortunately) using other is not an option.
For practical reasons I create my Java projects inside a Dropbox folder of the current subject but a couple of days ago when I had to Run a project it suddenly prompted on the Output the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication44.JavaApplication44
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am aware that this is a common problem and I have tried the following:

- Reinstalling NetBeans & JDK
- Relocating the main class using the preferences menu of the current project.

So here comes the problem, after reinstalling again and having tried all sort of possible solutions, I created a project (again) in the Dropbox folder to know if the issue disappeared but it didn't, then I created a project in the Desktop and it suddenly worked. After a bit of trial and error the problem is my Dropbox folder because when I create a simple project like a Hello World, I am 100% the code is correct, inside another place it works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox might be creating hidden files that are causing your IDE to fail on this project.

I would consider using some code versioning tool instead of Dropbox, like Git or Subversion. With Git, you can easily host your project for free on [GitHub](https://github.com/) (public repository only) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (public or private repositories).

Comment: The problem is that two days ago it worked but suddenly it changed, seems a bit strange to me. Is there a possibility to know if that hidden files that are being created affect my project?